# Integral converge

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, parameter-estimation

For which values of parameter $\alpha$ does the integral converge?
$$\int\limits_A^\infty \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^{\alpha}}, \; \text{where } \; \alpha\in(0,1)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^\alpha} \sim \frac{1}{x^{2\alpha}}, x \to \infty$$